# Splitting the state vector when solving a series of odes using python odeint scipy

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, scipy, odeint

I'm converting my code from Matlab to Python and stuck on how to split the state vector such that the result returns the two solution. I have a vector and a single value for the two initial conditions and I expect as the final result a matrix and a vector.

I tried joining the initial conditions (y0 = [c_pt_0, x_0]) in the same manner as the solution (soln = [dfdt,dcdt]) (which is shown below in the code). I also tried a similar approach that is used in matlab, which is concatenating the the initial conditions to one single array and unpacking the results but I think the problem is in the dimensions.

```
#Basic imports
import numpy as np
import pylab
import matplotlib. pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define parameters
pi = 3.14159265 
V_m = 9.09
m_V__M_Pt = 1e6/195.084    
rho = 21.45
R0 = 10**(-8.19)
k_d = 10**(-13)
k_r = 10**(-5)
S = 0.314   #distribution parameter
M = 0.944   #distribution parameter

## geometry
# Finite Volume Method with equidistant elements
r_max = 30.1e-9                     #maximum value
n = 301                             #number of elements of FVM
dr = r_max/n                        #length of elements, equidistant
ini_r = np.linspace(5e-10,r_max,n+1)    #boundaries of elements
mid_r = ini_r[0:n]+dr/2             #center of elements

## initial conditions
#initial distribution
x0 = 1/(S*np.sqrt(2*pi)*mid_r*1e9)*np.exp((-(np.log(mid_r*1e9)-M)**2)/(2*S**2))
c_pt_0 = 0
y0 = [x0, c_pt_0]

MN_0 = scipy.trapz(np.power(mid_r, 3)*x0,
                        x=mid_r)    # initial mass
M_0 = 4/3*pi*rho*MN_0

def f(y, t):
    r = y[0]
    c_pt = y[1]

    #materials balance
    drdt = V_m * k_r * c_pt * np.exp(-R0/ mid_r) - V_m * k_d * np.exp(R0/ mid_r)
    dmdt = 4*pi*rho*mid_r**2*drdt
    dMdt = np.trapz(r*dmdt, x=mid_r)

    dcdt = m_V__M_Pt*(-dMdt)/M_0
    dfdt = -(np.gradient(r*drdt, dr))

    soln = [dfdt, dcdt]
    return soln

#------------------------------------------------------
#define timespace
time = np.linspace(0, 30, 500)

#solve ode system
sln_1 = odeint (f , y0 , time,
    rtol = 1e-3, atol = 1e-5)

pylab.plot(mid_r, sln_1[1,:], color = 'r', marker = 'o')
pylab.plot(mid_r, sln_1[-1,:], color = 'b', marker = 'o')
plt.show()
```

Traceback:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT: ADDED MATLAB CODE**

Here is the MATLAB code that works that I want to convert to python where the state vector is split. I have three files (one main, the f function, and the parameters). Please excuse any *face palm* coding errors but I do appreciate any suggestions even for this.

modified_model.m:

```
function modified_model

% import parameters
p = cycling_parameters;

% initial conditions
c_pt_0 = 0;
y0 = [p.x0; c_pt_0];

% call integrator 
options_ODE=odeset('Stats','on', 'RelTol',1e-3,'AbsTol',1e-5);
[~, y] = ode15s(@(t,y) f(t, y, p), p.time, y0, options_ODE);

%% Post processing
% split state vector
r       = y(:,1:p.n);
c_Pt = y(:,p.n+1);

%% Plot results 

figure
hold on;
plot(p.r_m, r(1,:));
plot(p.r_m, r(end,:));
xlabel({'size'},'FontSize',15)
ylabel({'counts'},'FontSize',15)
```

f.m

```
function soln = f(~, y, p)

%split state vector
r = y(1:p.n);
c_pt = y(p.n+1);

% materials balance
drdt = p.Vm_Pt.*p.k_rdp.*c_pt.*exp(-p.R0./p.r_m) - p.Vm_Pt.*p.k_dis.*exp(p.R0./p.r_m);
dmdt = 4*pi*p.rho*p.r_m.^2.*drdt; 
dMdt = trapz(p.r_m, r.*dmdt);
dcdt = p.I_V*p.m_V__M_Pt*(-dMdt)/p.M_0;
dfdt = - gradient(r.*drdt,p.dr);

soln = [dfdt; dcdt];
```

and the parameters file: cycling_parameters.m

```
function p=cycling_parameters

p.M = 195.084; 
p.rho = 21.45;       
p.time = linspace(0, 30, 500);
p.m_V__M_Pt = 1e6/p.M;     

p.Vm_Pt = 9.09;  

p.R0_log = -8.1963; 
p.k_dis_log = -13; 
p.k_rdp_log = -11;

p.R0 = 10^(p.R0_log);
p.k_dis = 10^(p.k_dis_log);
p.k_rdp = 10^(p.k_rdp_log);

%%% geometry %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Finite Volume Method with equidistant elements 
p.r_max = 10.1e-9;                    % [m] maximum radius of PRD

p.n = 301;                          % number of elements of FVM

p.dr = p.r_max/p.n;                 % [m] length of elements, equidistant
p.r = linspace(5e-10,p.r_max,p.n+1)';   % [m] boundaries of elements
p.r_m = p.r(1:p.n)+p.dr/2;          % [m] center of elements

%log normal initial distribution

S = 0.314; 
M = 0.944; 
p.x0 = 1./(S.*sqrt(2.*pi).*p.r_m*1e9).*exp((-(log(p.r_m*1e9)-M).^2)./(2.*S.^2));


p.r_squared = p.r_m.^2; % [m^2] squares of the radius (center of elements)
p.r_cubed   = p.r_m.^3; % [m^3] cubes of the radius (center of elements)
p.MN_0 = trapz(p.r_m, p.r_cubed.*p.x0);   % Eq. 2.11 denominator
p.M_0 = 4/3*pi*p.rho*p.MN_0;  
p.I_V = 1; %ionomer volume fraction in the catalyst layer
```

Comment: Just from the code you posted, I can see one major issue is that you are trying to index at -1:

`sln_1[-1,:]`

That's not going to work, the lowest index is zero. A couple other things: you need to convert those 'e's to `*10**(9)`, the: `np.linspace(5e-10,r_max,n+1)` is not what you want to use for step sizing. You want np.arange(start, end, time_step). You also are calling pylab.plot wrong, you need to do `plt.pylab.plot`

Comment: One of the issues is your `y0`; it should be just two numbers in your case, but instead you have one sequence of numbers and one single value. The other issue is your function `f`; if you check `f([0.1, 0.1], 1)` you should also just see a list of two values, but instead you have a list with an array and one value.

Comment: Thank for your responses. @Cleb that's correct, the main issue is I don't just have two numbers for my initial condition (or answer) as you mentioned since it's a system of equations (one with a series and one not). If I changed the function to omit c_pt as just a variable and not a derivative (dcdt), the code works. But when I go to add in the system of equation it throws the error so I'm wondering how to handle this in python. So when I just use x0 (301,) as the initial condition my result is (301,500). I want to add c_pt to the system such that I have dfdt as (301,500) and c_pt as (1,500).

Comment: I think I do not fully understand the issue. From my understanding, when you have `n` equations, you have exactly `n` initial conditions, so both, `y0` as well as the output of `f` should be of length `n` where each item in the list/array is a single number. When I now print your `y0`, it is indeed of length 2, however, `y0[0]` is of length 301 but should be a single value. I don't understand what a series as initial value could possible represent and that is independent on your dimension of your system. Same holds for `f`.

Comment: @AnnaNevison admittedly my code is not the cleanest but all those things you mentioned are not the issue, the code works fine with those (as detailed more in the previous comment). But I do appreciate notes to clean it up since I'm not an all-star python user. As for ' sln_1[-1,:] ', it is plotting the last series in the 301,500 matrix (and works, same as sln_1[300,:] would) so not sure of another way to do that. Cheers.

Comment: @Cleb, it is a bit confusing let's see if I can clear it up. So I have dfdt that is a function of drdt which is a function of dcdt. dcdt (concentration) has one initial condition, 0. drdt has a function as an initial condition (x0 with dimensions (301,). This means the systems solves drdt (radius changing with time) at each radius thus the output dimension is (301,500). Does this make sense?

Comment: @HeatherB. No worries, I can't really see what else would be wrong besides those minor things... but would you mind posting the original MATLAB code?

Comment: @AnnaNevison yep, that's a good idea. I'll edit my question but it will take a minute because I have to condense the code  since my real problem is slightly more complex.

Comment: I still do not get it but I will also wait for the matlab code, it might then become a bit clearer for a slow mind as mine :)

Comment: @AnnaNevison, added the MATLAB code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at both codes, the issue is that the odeint solver only takes 1D array inputs and your y0 is [int, array(300,)] and odeint can't work with that. However, you can merge the y0 into a 1D array and then split it up in the function you are integrating over to do the calculation then recombine as the output. Here's a working code of that:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class P:
    def __init__(self, S, M):
        self.M = 195.084
        self.rho = 21.45
        self.m_V__M_Pt = (1*10**6)/self.M
        self.Vm_Pt = 9.09
        self.R0_log = -8.1963
        self.k_dis_log = -13
        self.k_rdp_log = -11
        self.R0 = 10**(self.R0_log)
        self.k_dis = 10**(self.k_dis_log)
        self.k_rdp = 10**(self.k_rdp_log)
        self.r_max = 10.1*10**(-9)
        self.n = 301
        self.dr = self.r_max / self.n
        self.r = np.linspace(5*10**(-10), self.r_max, self.n)
        self.r_m = self.r[0:self.n+1]+self.dr/2
        self.x0 = self.compute_x0(S, M)
        self.r_squared = np.power(self.r_m, 2)
        self.r_cubed = np.power(self.r_m, 3)
        self.MN_0 = np.trapz(self.r_m, np.multiply(self.r_cubed, self.x0))
        self.M_0 = (4 / 3)* np.pi * self.rho * self.MN_0
        self.I_V = 1

    def compute_x0(self, S, M):
        p1 = np.multiply(2, np.power(S, 2))
        p2 = np.multiply(S, np.sqrt(np.multiply(2, np.pi)))
        p3 = np.log(self.r_m*1*10**(9)) - M
        p4 = np.multiply(p2, self.r_m*10**(9))
        p5 = np.power(-p3, 2)
        p6 = np.multiply(p4, np.exp(np.divide(p5,p1)))
        p7 = np.divide(1, p6)
        return p7

def cycling_parameters():
    S = 0.314
    M = 0.944
    p = P(S, M)
    return p

def f(y, t):
    p = cycling_parameters()
    c_pt = y[0]
    r = np.delete(y, 0)
    p1 = np.multiply(p.Vm_Pt, p.k_rdp)
    p2 = np.multiply(p1, c_pt)
    p3 = np.multiply(p.Vm_Pt, p.k_dis)
    drdt = np.multiply(p2, np.exp(np.divide(-p.R0, p.r_m))) - np.multiply(p3, np.exp(np.divide(p.R0, p.r_m)))
    dmdt = np.multiply(4*np.pi*p.rho*np.power(p.r_m, 2), drdt)
    p4 = np.multiply(r, dmdt)
    dMdt = np.trapz(p.r_m, p4)
    dcdt = p.I_V*p.m_V__M_Pt*(-dMdt)/p.M_0
    p5 = np.multiply(r, drdt)
    dfdt = - np.gradient(p5,p.dr)
    ans = np.insert(dfdt, 0, dcdt)
    return ans

def modified_model():
    p = cycling_parameters()
    c_pt_0 = 0
    y0 = np.insert(p.x0, 0, c_pt_0)
    t = np.linspace(0, 30, 500)
    ans = odeint(f, y0, t, rtol = 1e-3, atol = 1e-5)

    r = ans[:, 1:p.n+1]
    c_Pt = ans[:, 0]
    print(r)
    print(c_Pt)
    plt.plot(p.r_m, r[0, :], color='r', linewidth=0.5)
    plt.plot(p.r_m, r[r.shape[0]-1, :], color='b', linewidth=0.5)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    modified_model()
```

Python plot (what this script outputs):

[image]

Original Matlab Plot:

[image]